# Azure Storage / Table - Read Lock

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I've been using Azure table storage for a while. I created a new storage account and an app configured to write log data to a table via Serilog.

Today, I tried to reach the table from the Azure portal and I got the message: "Cannot access the data plane because of a read lock on the resource or its parent"

[image]

If I select "Locks" from the Storage Account window I get the message "This resource has no locks".

Any ideas why this would suddenly happen and how I can resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Doh! It was because I'd reached my monthly spend limit. Hope this save someone time in the future.